# Disjoint Set algorithm for large data sets

Tags: algorithm, set

Currently I'm working on a problem which involves creating disjoint sets out of a large data set which is 165GB in size. The algorithm used now is union by rank algorithm. However the size of the dataset doesn't permit to contain all the data in the memory at once(part of the data reside in a database while other part being processed in the memory).

But the problem is it takes much time when searching for a element's existency within already created sets(This takes O(n2) time).

Appreciate if anyone can provide a solution to above problem

Comment: You'll need to explain in a bit more detail what your problem looks like. I can break `{1, 2, 3, ...}` up into disjoint sets `{{1}, {2}, {3}, ...}` very easily and quickly, so I suppose that's not what you had in mind.

Comment: @Thomas yes this problem is really easy when it comes to small data sets. but in my case it is too large that part of it resides outside the memory. Supose currently the algorithm have created 100000 sets(some of these sets may not in memory) and now it has element 5.In that case 5 needs to be searched in every set to determine if it already exist. This is what I need to optimize.

Comment: The [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) does not dictate how the nodes should be stored. You can put them in a database instead of in main memory, and it shouldn't affect the (big-O) efficiency of the algorithm. So I really don't see where the O(n²) comes from.

Comment: Are you just trying to find connected components or is it important to have online use of the disjoint set data structure?

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to slice and dice this.

My suggestion would be in a single pass to assign an incrementing index to each element of the large data set.  Then create a bit-vector of the right size to indicate "in the union of all currently assigned sets".  That bit-vector should be small enough to fit into memory.